# The difference between updateMask and multiply

Tags: google-earth-engine

https://code.earthengine.google.com/aa585a5ed8118e2664c3344eb96ecb6f

Here's the code. I was trying calculated the area where NDVI>0.8. The I find that masking in GEE works by weighting each pixel by the mask in calculations. So I wonder what is the difference between multiply and updateMask.

And why I still get two different calculated area reuslts?

```
var cloudMaskL457 = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  var cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5)
          .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7))
          .or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3))
  var mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min());

  return image.updateMask(cloud.not()).updateMask(mask2);
};
function NDVI(img) {
 var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["B4","B3"]).rename("ndvi");
 return img.addBands(ndvi).clip(dianchi)
 
}

 var   dianchi = ee.FeatureCollection("users/lixiaonayu/border/dianchi");
// var S1=ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR")
// .filterBounds(dianchi)
//           .filterDate('2000-01-01','2000-12-31')
//           .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',30))
//           .map(cloudMaskL457)

 var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
          .filterBounds(dianchi)
          .filterDate('2000-09-01','2000-10-01')
          .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',30))
          .map(cloudMaskL457)
//print(S1,"S1");
print(S2,"S2");


var img=S2.map(NDVI).first().select("ndvi")

var data=img.select("ndvi")
var mask=data.gt(0.8)
Map.addLayer(mask,{},"mask")
var areamask1=mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
Map.addLayer(areamask1,{},"areamask1")

var areamask2 =ee.Image.pixelArea().updateMask(mask);

Map.addLayer(areamask2,{},"areamask2")
var area1=areamask1.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: dianchi,
    // crs: 'EPSG:32645', // WGS Zone N 45
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13
  });
print(area1.get("ndvi"),  'area1')

var area2=areamask2.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: dianchi,
    // crs: 'EPSG:32645', // WGS Zone N 45
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1E13
  });
print(area2.get("area"),  'area5')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get a slightly different answer because you didn't specify a CRS, and the computations are being computed using different projections (the projection of the mask vs the projection of pixelArea).  When you specify the CRS, they are identical.